# DB2: add a "day" modifier when using between clause

Tags: db2, between

Hi I want to implement the following between clause in sql db2:

```
between start_date - 1 days and end_date
```

where start_date and end_date are standard dates, and I want to search between the day before the start_date up to the end_date. I however get the following error:

```
An expression with a datetime value or a labeled duration is not valid
```

however if I try:

```
between start_date and end_date + 1 days
```

there are no complaints. how do I get the first clause to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using parentheses?

Comment: doh. silly error from me. thanks Warren. never underestimate the importance of parentheses.